# How to install Numpy without compiling the sources

Tags: numpy, compilation, centos, pip

I have a project running on CentOS7 that uses Numpy. 
The problem is that it takes a very huge amount of time to install this dependency.

I therefore tried to `yum install` numpy libs before `pip install` it.

So I run:

```
yum install numpy-1.7.1
pip install numpy==1.7.1   # This pip is executed in a virtualenv
```

The `yum install` installs the packaged library, and is quite fast to be performed.
The weird thing is that the `pip install` command re-compile all the sources. This is strange because, from my understanding, the `pip install` shall only add the python bindings on the compiled lib previously installed.

Any idea to get this library installed without to have everything recompiled?

Comment: To be clear, after using the package manager to install numpy to the system (`yum install numpy`) you can't `import numpy` in a python shell? To my understanding, the second step, `pip install` should be unnecessary. Have you tried starting the python interpreter in importing numpy?

Comment: Indeed the `yum install` install the package globally. But I need to install it into a virtual env, that's why I run the `pip install`

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by symlinking the 'global lib' (installed by `yum install`) into the virtual env:

```
ln -s /lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy $VENV/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy
ln -s /lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.7.1-py2.7.egg-info $ENV/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.7.1-py2.7.egg-info
```